# Python 3.8 won't run "hello" script

Tags: python

I finally pulled the trigger, started learning to code python.

It was working just fine yesterday, now it isn't.

Here is what it is doing now-

[image: Script not working in terminal via interpreter(?)]

However, I believe there is nothing wrong with the code because Thonny runs it just fine-

[image: SCript working in Thonny]

My system info is-

[image: version of ubuntu]

All of these shenanigans are occurring on the raspberry pi 4 b w/8gb of ram etc...

I checked out this question over [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243551/python-3-8-scripts-suddenly-wont-run-but-python-commands-run-fine-when-invoked) but frankly I'm so new to this it was mostly over my head.  I tried rebooting and power off.  This is probably a *derp* error, but this set of eyes is simply not seeing the painfully obvious problem that seasons devs could spot a mile away.

Please help.  Python version running is 3.8.6

Comment: Why do you run python in interactive way? Just run `python3 exone.py` from _shell command line_? And please never put pictures in your question, when you can just copy and paste the _text_ from your terminal!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command line system is **already** running inside the Python shell.

Your prompt is `>>>` which is the Python interpreter prompt - you don't execute your Python program directly from that.  Type `exit()`, and it'll drop you back to your normal shell prompt.  Then, just run `python3 exone.py` from there.

Answer (score 0):

You are already in the python interpreter, don't need to run `>>> python3 ...`.

To execute a file inside the interpreter use this command:

Example file `py.py`:

```
print('Hello World')
```

Enter the python interpreter:

```
$ python3
```

```py
>>> exec(open("py.py").read())
Hello world
```